# Dynamic attribute as key for posting a JSON using Restkit in iOS

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I am using RestKit 0.9.4. I would like to post a JSON that has a key that needs to be populated from an object's attribute. 
The JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "types":[ {
        "1" : "value1"
     },
     {  
         "7" : "value2"
     } ]
}
```

I have an object with 2 NSString data members named keytype and value respectively .
keytype is the variable that has the values that appear for the key in the nested json above ( "1", "7" etc above ). **mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute** will probably not work here because the dynamic attribute( to be used as key) is at the inner most level..
Can this be posted using RestKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you make that structure in an NSDictionary, and then post it as JSON using RestKit. Also, the response then maps to a model.

```
// make the inner dictionaries (probably would use a for loop for this
NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"1", nil];
NSDictionary *dict7 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value2", @"7", nil];
// put them in an array
NSArray *types = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict1, dict7, nil];
// now put the array in a dictionary
NSDictionary *finalDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:types, @"types", nil];

// create a JSON string from your NSDictionary
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalDict 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] init];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

// make the post using the objectManager if you want to map the response to a model
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];  
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/" delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; // We want to send this request as JSON
    loader.objectMapping = [objectManager.mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Plan class]];
    loader.resourcePath = @"/api/";
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    loader.params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
}];
```